# How select value like column in DataTable DotNet?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My code:

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
     dt.Columns.Add("No")
     dt.Columns.Add("Col2")
      Dim dr = dt.NewRow
     dr("No") = 1
     dr("Col2") = "abc"
     dt.Rows.Add(dr)
 Dim strText="abcdes"
 For Each drow As DataRow In dt.Select(String.Format("'{0}' like '%' & Col2 & '%'", strText)) 
 //value of Col2 exist in strText
 Next
```

It show error:

> {"The expression contains unsupported operator
>   '&'."}    System.Data.EvaluateException

How select value like column in DataTable DotNet?

Comment: You don't need `&`, just correct the format for `LIKE`.

Comment: If Remove & : "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Col2' operator."} System.Data.SyntaxErrorException

Comment: Notes: Col2 is ColumnName

Comment: Check the answer  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `+` instead of `&` and correct the format for `LIKE`:

```
String.Format(" '{0}' LIKE '%' + Col2 + '%' ", strText)
```

For each row, this checks if the value of `Col2` is contained in `strText` it returns the row.

To check if `Col2` contains `strText`, you should use `String.Format("Col2 LIKE '%{0}%'", strText)`.

**Example**:

```
Dim foundRows() As DataRow
foundRows= dt.Select(String.Format(" '{0}' LIKE '%' + Col2 + '%' ", strText))
For Each dr As DataRow In foundRows
    'Do something
Next
```

To learn more about expression syntax:

- [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Note:**

If instead of getting a list of `DataRow`, you need to Filter a `DataTable`, for example to show only filtered rows in a `DataGridView`, use:

```
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Col2 LIKE '%{0}%'", strText)
```

Comment: I want select value like Colum Name: The same query in sql: select * from TableA  where 'F3' like '%' & Columname & '%'

Comment: So, This is exactly what you need. It returns rows that `Col2` of them, contains the value in `strText`.

Comment: This is expression syntax, it's not completely same as sql syntax.

Comment: It not working:  With Data in my Question:  Dim dtbl = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(): Result: dtbl is nothing.

Comment: I believe the post answers your question :) if you debut and trace your code, surely you will see where the problem is. for example you may have entered `sometext` in text box, while you have `SomeText` in column.

Comment: Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("No")
dt.Columns.Add("Col2")
Dim drd = dt.NewRow
drd("No") = 1
drd("Col2") = "abc"
dt.Rows.Add(drd)
Dim strText = "abcdes"
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Col2 LIKE '%{0}%'", strText)
Dim dtbl = dt.DefaultView.ToTable().    //This is all my code testing.

Comment: The problem is obviously in last 2 lines of code. As I said in answer you should use `dt.Select("some filter")` or `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter="some filter"`

Comment: Also please don't edit the question, this makes the answers misleading for future readers. I rolled back the edit  :)

Comment: If you want to use the result in a for loop, you should use `For Each drow As DataRow In in dt.Select("some filter")`

Comment: The problem of my question: Value like Column, not Column like value

Comment: This is expression syntax, it's not completely same as sql syntax.

Comment: can't get rows have value of Col2 exist in strText

Comment: (1) Search is case sensitive. (2) How you say you can't get the rows?

Comment: String.Format("Col2 LIKE '%{0}%'", strText) get value of rows have value contain strText., not value of Col2 exist in strText

Comment: Ex: [select * from TableA  where 'F3' like '%' & type & '%']
difference
[select * from TableA    where type like '%F3%']

Comment: I Got What you mean! use `String.Format(" '{0}' LIKE '%' + Col2 + '%' ", strText)`

Comment: The short answer is you should use `+` instead of `&`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and sorry for misunderstanding :)

Comment: By the way it would be great when you accept an answer, you also kindly vote for answer by click on up arrow. It's not compulsory at all but it's reasonable, [recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) and your kindness :)

Answer (score 1):

While building the correct Filter value for a LIKE condition, you have to take care of the special characters.

There is an example [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

```
public static string EscapeLikeValue(string valueWithoutWildcards)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < valueWithoutWildcards.Length; i++)
  {
    char c = valueWithoutWildcards[i];
    if (c == '*' || c == '%' || c == '[' || c == ']')
      sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]");
    else if (c == '\'')
      sb.Append("''");
    else
      sb.Append(c);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

And as others mentioned, your syntax looks odd, try

```
dt.Select(String.Format("col2 LIKE '%{0}%'", EscapeLikeValue(strText))
```

Comment: Can use EscapeLikeValue to value of Col2?

Comment: @DT Just for clarification: Do you want to find every row where col2 contains 'abcdes' or do you want to find every row where 'abcdes' contains the value from col2?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing dt.AsEnumerable() and using LINQ functions?

In your case you can do something similar

`var dataRows = dt.AsEnumerable(); 
var matchingRows = dataRows.Where(e=>e.Row<string>("Col2").Contains(strText)).Select();`

This will return an IEnumerable which has all the rows that contain the value of strText

It's much easier to read and a much more preferred way.